# How to select all text in a tk input box (ruby)

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

Just coming up to speed with tk / ruby.

I have a very simple window with a one line text input area, a "go" button, and a feedback label.

The desired behavior is that a user enters some text, hits the "go" button, and the code does some work.

When its all over the input box should have the text entered, but it should be highlighted and the focus in the input box, so that if the user begins typing again what was in the box will be overwritten.

In .net this was pretty easy, just say .selectall to the input field.  can't figure out how to do it in tk.

```
    root = TkRoot.new {title "Test App"}
content = Tk::Tile::Frame.new(root) {padding "3 3 12 12"}.grid( :sticky => 'nsew')
TkGrid.columnconfigure root, 0, :weight => 1; TkGrid.rowconfigure root, 0, :weight => 1
$job= TkVariable.new; $status = TkVariable.new
$j = Tk::Tile::Entry.new(content) {
      width 14; textvariable $job}.grid( :column => 1, :row => 1, :sticky => 'we' )
Tk::Tile::Button.new(content) {
         text 'Find Job'
         command {go_do_something}
       }.grid( :column => 2, :row => 1, :sticky => 'w')

    def go_do_something
       # ... do some processing, then I want to...
       # $j.focus
       # $j.select_all
    end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had to use winapi to get the focus back to the window, then do a $j.focus; $j.selection_range(0,100).   Is there any easier way to get the focus back to the app then going through a bunch of windows API calls?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add all of the widget's text to the special "sel" (selection) tag.

What your sw adds to the sel tag will become selected on the screen.

See [docs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#selection)

Comment: That is what I wanted to do.   I did have trouble with the order which appears important.  First focus then select.

Answer (score 1):

Order is important:

```
$j.focus; 
$j.selection_range(0,100)
```

This works to get the text box selected.   Getting the focus back to the window is another question I will ask elsewhere.